# How to extract all div elements with a specific id and a specific class?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I have a html

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
<div id="aa" class="aa"> This I don't want </div>
<div id="a a" class="b b"> <div id="cc" class="dd"> This I want </div></div>
<div id="aa" class="cc">This I don't want</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")
```

that I want to use `BeautifulSoup` to extract the element

```
<div id="a a" class="b b"> <div id="cc" class="dd">
```

Is there a syntax to enforce the following ideas?

1. We want to extract an element contain two div's where the first div is characterized by `id="aa" class="bb"` and the second div by `div id="cc" class="dd"`.
2. As above but two div's are consecutive. Usually, I use `a > b` to signify that `b` is right after `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to select `<div>` with `id="aa"` and `class="bb"`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_text = """\
<div id="aa" class="aa">This I don't want</div>
<div id="aa" class="bb">This I want</div>
<div id="aa" class="cc">This I don't want</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

print(soup.select("div#aa.bb"))
```

Prints:

```
[<div class="bb" id="aa">This I want</div>]
```

---

If you want to select multiple `id=`, you can do:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
<div id="aa" class="xx">This I don't want</div>
<div id="bb" class="yy">This I want</div>
<div id="cc" class="zz">This I want</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

print(soup.select("div#bb, div#cc"))
```

Prints:

```
[
  <div class="yy" id="bb">This I want</div>, 
  <div class="zz" id="cc">This I want</div>
]
```

---

EDIT:

```py
html_text = """\
<div id="aa" class="aa"> This I don't want </div>
<div id="aa" class="bb"> <div id="cc" class="dd"> This I want </div></div>
<div id="aa" class="cc">This I don't want</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")
print(soup.select("div#aa.bb:has(> div#cc.dd)"))
```

Prints:

```
[<div class="bb" id="aa"> <div class="dd" id="cc"> This I want </div></div>]
```

Comment: I have edited my question to add more requirement. Could you have a look on it?

Comment: I wonder if there is something like `soup.select('div[id="a a", class="b b"] div[id="cc", class="dd"]')`? This kind of "syntax" seems more flexible...

Comment: It seems `soup.select("div#a a.b b")` does not work if we want to extract `<div id="a a" class="b b">This I want</div>`. Do you have any idea in this situation with whitespace.

Comment: @Akira `class="a b"` means, that the tag is of class `a` **and** of class `b`. So to select the tag that has class `a` and class `b` you use `div.a.b`